# Need help in assigning each variable of dynamic array separately to a data field

Tags: python, arrays

I want to assign each variable in array separately to a data field. But length of array changes dynamically.

For example:
px_last array can have 2 values or 3 values or any number of values

> data=[px_last[0], px_last[1]]

or

> data=[px_last[0], px_last[1], px_last[2]]

I am assigning each values in `px_last` array to data. But length of array changes dynamically. How to add all the values in array individually to data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `list comprehension`:

`data = [x for x in px_last]`

Answer (score 2):

It should be simple as:

```
data = list(px_data)
```